# Unable to rename files in samba share

Tags: rename, samba, cifs

I'm accessing a samba share on a Windows Server 2019 from a PC with an updated Debian 10 buster OS with the command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=3.11,username=myname,uid=1000,gid=1000 //the.server/some/share/ /home/myname/some/dir
```

On the top level I'm able to create and rename files without problems:

```
>> cd ~/some/dir
>> touch del.me
>> mv del.me del1.me
```

However, if I try to rename a file in a subdirectory, it doesn't work anymore:

```
>> cd ~/some/dir
>> mkdir subdir
>> cd subdir
>> touch del.me
>> ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 myname myname    0 Apr 27 11:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 myname myname 8192 Apr 27 11:56 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myname myname    0 Apr 27 11:56 del.me
>> mv del.me del1.me    
mv: cannot move 'del.me' to 'del1.me': No such file or directory
```

Deleting the file created in the subdirectory with `rm del.me` works without problems.

What could be the reason? I've tried looking online for the problem but cannot find a solution. In other shares on the same server (`//the.server/another/share/`) mounted in the same way and with the same permissions, moving files works without problems. I've also tried accessing the share from a different PC (running a Debian testing OS), and the problem persists. My samba version is 4.9.5-Debian.

Comment: Can you `cat del.me` or `ls -l del.me`?

Comment: @roaima The `ls -l` is shown above. For the example shown, since I just "touched" it, `del.me` is empty, but I have the problem with files with content too. Running `cat` doesn't give any errors

Comment: I saw your `ls -l`, I'm curious to know about the `ls -l del.me` with an explicitly referenced file name

Comment: @roaima The output is the same (`-rwxr-xr-x 1 myname myname    0 Apr 27 11:56 del.me`)

Comment: So the problem isn't referencing the source filename, it's about referencing the destination. Does `mv` object to naming `del.me` to something other than `del1.me`? Can you `cat del1.me` / `ls -dl del1.me` (i.e. referencing the `mv` target filename even though it shouldn't exist)?

Comment: @roaima The problem persists no matter what the destination file name is. Trying to `ls` the unexisting file destination results in `ls: cannot access 'del1.me': No such file or directory`

Comment: Seems to me it's probably inheritable permissions from the share root on Windows Server. Although I'm struggling to work out what permission exists (or is denied) that would prevent the rename. Possibly `Modify`. Is there someone who understands Windows ACLs who can check that side for you?

Comment: @roaima I spoke with my IT admin (he was aware of the problem but couldn't fix it either) and he resetted my permissions, but it still doesn't work. Since the problem persists across different machines and only affects linux (while on Windows I can rename files without problems) I guess that **a)** either the mount command (protocol version/special flags needed/...?) is wrong or **b)** there is some kinf of incompatibility between linux machines (cifs/samba/...?) and the server, but I really don't know where else to look at. I have also checked if `mv` points to the right binary.

Comment: Are you using the same username for the Linux CIFS mount that you use on Windows?

Comment: Please add `noperm` to the mount options and try again

Comment: @roaima `noperm` doesn't work either. The login name is the same...

Comment: @roaima I fixed the problem specifying `vers=1.0`. I had already tried `3.11`, `3.0` and `2.0` but had to go back even further. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed specifying version 1.0:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o vers=1.0,username=myname,uid=1000,gid=1000 //the.server/some/share/ /home/myname/some/dir
```

The bug affects debian systems and is known since January 2021: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=949394

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen this error even `sudo rm del.me` didn't work for me. Touching the "nonexistent" file and then `rm`-ing did.